# dom manipulation- How to properly use createElement?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand why it isn't displaying the text after I click on the button? Is there something I'm missing?

HTML:

```
<button id="myBtn" onClick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(){
"use strict";
var newpara = document.createElement("p");
var newcontent = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the `newpara` element to the document in order for it to be displayed on the webpage. Also, you should add the created text node to your paragraph element

Consider the following additions:

```
function myFunction(){
"use strict";
var newpara = document.createElement("p");
var newcontent = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");

// [ADD] Ensure that content is added to the paragraph element
newpara.appendChild(newcontent);

// [ADD] Ensure the paragraph element is added to the document
document.body.appendChild(newpara);    
}
```

Comment: This will not show the text in the paragraph. You still have to append the text to the p.

Comment: @Michel please see updated answer -  are you noticing an error with this?

Comment: Not anymore, Edit and comment where milliseconds apart :-) Will retract the downvote.

Comment: @Michel no problems :-) at first I was just answering to show complete usage of `createElement` but then edited answer to ensure the text display was working also

Comment: On a sidenote: `document.append()` isn't working in IE11 and Edge <16, `document.appendChild()`  might be a better choice.

Comment: @Michel thanks for that suggestion - have applied update :-)

Comment: Because I'd never heard of [`parentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) (and because the answer works, obviously) I have to up-vote. Thanks! :) Incidentally, and there's no real incentive to follow through since I can't up-vote again or anything, could you also explain why unobtrusive JavaScript is a better approach, and how it might be used ([`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), for example).